Failed to execute (TrainDeepLearningModel) ArcGIS Pro
I was using pre-trained model for human settlement landsat-8 for collecting residential area in ArcGIS Pro. Because the result was not good, i tried to follow this article (https://doc.arcgis.com/en/pretrained-models/latest/imagery/finetuning-the-human-settlements-classification-landsat-8-.htm) hoping it works.
However, i got this error message as shown below:
Error message
I did some research about the size mismatch errors, but since the publisher did not specify the trained data, I was hardly to understand the structure.
for this error code, per now, I still cannot find any relevant article

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'training_model_object' referenced before assignment

Can anyone please explain what the error messages mean and what possible step can I do? I really appreciate any input and help!
